# querying a JSON array of integers for the presence of a value in MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-json

I have a MySQL 5.7 table that looks like this:

| id | meta |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | null |
| 2 | {"grant_ids": [5, 7]} |

I'd like to query for rows that have the presence of the value of 5 in meta-> grant_ids.
I tried

```
select *   from content.banners where meta->>"$.grant_ids" in (5);
```

but not working. I don't think `in` is supported but any ideas how to achieve this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> create table table_that_looks_like_this ( 
  id int primary key, meta json);

mysql> insert into table_that_looks_like_this values
    -> (1, null),
    -> (2, '{"grant_ids": [5, 7]}'),
    -> (3, '{"grant_ids": [4, 8]}'),
    -> (4, '{"no_grant_ids": [5, 7]}');

mysql> select * from table_that_looks_like_this 
 where json_contains(meta, '[5]', '$.grant_ids');
+----+-----------------------+
| id | meta                  |
+----+-----------------------+
|  2 | {"grant_ids": [5, 7]} |
+----+-----------------------+
```

[DBFiddle](https://%20https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uwcA3FuU1f49H8hgzRFjji/0)

JSON_EXTRACT() will only return the JSON array at the path you give, and an array isn't the scalar value 5. Unquoting a JSON array with the `->>` operator has no effect; an "unquoted" JSON array is the exact same array.

Comment: thx Bill, I really enjoy your books and strongly recommend them to other people (and don't tell me this exact example is in them lol); I appreciate you answering this question - I never would've figure this out myself. It looks as if you don't even need the brackets in the `where json_contains(meta, '5', '$.grant_ids');`

Comment: I'm working on a book now with a chapter about storing JSON in an SQL database. The summary is: _don't._

Comment: Sounds interesting, it can be very treacherous for storing and I only use for denormalization / querying. Have found beneficial for that use case but have to be very careful and could understand a no-JSON in SQL db rule.

Comment: Using JSON to format result sets is mostly okay, but people get into trouble when they store JSON and then try to search within the fields of a JSON document as if they are normal columns. Basically if you see a JSON column referenced in the WHERE clause (or really any clause other than the select-list), it's a red flag. You might also like my presentation [How to Use JSON in MySQL Wrong](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-use-json-in-mysql-wrong).

Comment: Thx for link. I have more experience with PostgreSQL which does have index support for JSONB. Have also used for data in microservices (but again tricky) when a network call would be much slower. Thx

Comment: MySQL 8.0 also has support for indexes on JSON documents, but not GIN indexes like PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this, using the JSON function of SQL:

```sql
select *
from content.banners b
where JSON_EXTRACT(b.meta,"$.grant_ids") in (5)
```